# How to access textLabel frame

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I am trying to check the location of a TableViewCell's textLabel's frame.  (Eventually I will want to check if a tap is inside this frame).

```
MyCell *c = [self tableView:self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSLog(@"%@ is in rect: %@ ", c.textLabel.text, NSStringFromCGRect(c.textLabel.frame));
```

This gives me logs like:

> 984943658 is in rect: {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}

The name part works fine (the text is that number), but why is it giving me 0's for the frame?  I can see the text on screen, so it must be in a frame - why can't I get it?

Comment: Where do you put this snippet in?

Comment: Which method is this code called from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method of the table view data source delegate. That creates a new table view cell.

You probably want to call

```
[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

which returns the cell at the index path (if it is visible).